# Is any subset of $\mathbb{R}$ a Borel set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

Consider $S \subset \mathbb{R}$. Define for all $n \in \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$

\begin{align*}
S_n := \bigcup_{a \in S} \left (a - \frac{1}{n}, a + \frac{1}{n}\right)
\end{align*}

Since arbitrary union of open sets is open, $S_n$ is open for all $n$.

Now
\begin{align*}
S = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} S_n
\end{align*}

Hence $S$ is the intersection of countably many open sets, therefore, it is a Borel set.

Are my steps correct or is there something wrong? If there is something wrong, could you point out which step exactly?

Comment: If you start with $S = \Bbb Q$ then $S_n = \Bbb R$, and the intersection of all $S_n$ does *not* give the original set.

Comment: Understood. Thank you.

Comment: No reason in general to think that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}S_n$ is equal to $S$.  In fact, if $S$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, then that intersection is all of $\mathbb{R}$, which generally is $\neq S$.

Comment: Your assumption that $\bigcap S_n =S$ is false. Take $S=\mathbb Q.$ Then $S_n=\mathbb R$ for all $n.$

Comment: The correct phrasing of your question would be "Are all subsets... "

Comment: @sixtyTonneAngel I do appreciate the question. Descriptive set theory (a category that this question arguably falls into) is subtle and full of non-obvious counterexamples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your claim that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} S_n =S$ is false.

Take $S=\mathbb Q.$ Then $S_n=\mathbb R$ for all $n.$

More generally, the closure of $S$ is contained in $\bigcap S_n.$ You can prove that $\bigcap S_n=\overline S,$ but all closed sets are Borel already.